# MVC, DropDownListFor in partialview, onchange should store selected value _somewhere_

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view that is included in my _Layout.cshtml. 
This partial view contains a Dropdownlist, that gets correctly filled.

When the user selects a value, I want that value to be available everywhere else. So I tried to set it in my session data.

That works fine.

Partial view:

```
@model MyModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MySelection", "Home", new AjaxOptions()))
{
    var optionList = new SelectList(Model.Options, "Key", "Value");

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOption, optionList, 
    "--Select--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit(); return false;" })    
}
```

And, sure enough,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult MySelection(MyModel model)
    {
        Session["MySelection"] = model.SelectedOption;
        return PartialView("_MyPartial", model);
    }
```

Gets hit, sets the Session data, and returns the partial view.

However... that partial view is **all** I get to see! Instead of staying on the same page, only the partial view gets rendered.

I am running in circles trying to find out how I can just, simply, store the selected value to my session data, I do not need to have a view, partial view or anything returned, I do not need to reload data, reload a page, redirect to anywhere.

*What* is the (undoubtedly very simple!) way to get my selected option in my session data?

---

As Ehsan Sajjad suggested, after making sure everything else is in place, using a (hidden) button to submit the form will do an ajax-request, whereas the this.form.submit in the onchange handler does not!

So in short, now I have:

```
@model MyModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MySelection", "Home", new AjaxOptions()))
{
    var optionList = new SelectList(Model.Options, "Key", "Value");

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOption, optionList, 
    "--Select--", new { onchange = "submitButton.click();" }) 
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="hidden-button"/>   
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public void MySelection(MyModel model)
{
    Session["MySelection"] = model.SelectedOption;
}
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to return anything then return EmptyResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MySelection(MyModel model)
{
  Session["MySelection"] = model.SelectedOption;
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

other way around can be to use AjaxOptions as well, make a container div in main view:

```
<div id="container">

</div>



  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MySelection", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "conatainer" }))
 {
  var optionList = new SelectList(Model.Options, "Key", "Value");

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedOption, optionList, 
   "--Select--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit(); return false;" })
 }
```

and you can return empty content like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MySelection(MyModel model)
{
   Session["MySelection"] = model.SelectedOption;
   return Content("");
}
```

### UPDATED:

You need to add a hidden submit button and on drop down index change programmatically trigger its click, as programmatically submitting form not fires the original submit so the form is posted is not posted via ajax and full post back occurs.

Comment: If I return nothing, I see nothing. Literally. An empty page. That is my main problem. The data gets to the controller, but my page redirects to /Home/MySelection. Which is either only my partial view, or, if I return nothing, an empty page, or if I return a string, the value of that string.

Comment: yes, I included them, exactly as in your example except I corrected 'conatainer'.

Comment: in that case it only updated that container div not whole div, is jquery-unobtrusive.ajax is included your page post backs or partial post back?

Comment: jquery-unobtrusive.ajax is included in BundleConfig: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"). Including it explicitly in my view didn;t help either. It did not update only the div, it "refreshed" the whole page :(

Comment: it means your form is in posting via ajax its doing post back

Comment: can you check it is posting via ajax or postback occuring

Comment: I don;t know how to check "if postback is occurring", but if I check Request.IsAjaxRequest() it returns false. That means no ajax?

Comment: try adding a hidden submit button and on change of dropdown just click submit button programmatically may be programmatically form submit is not doing it via ajax

Comment: Trying first with a visible submit button - and yes, now it works as it should. Just twice... the code gets hit twice on a single button click.

Comment: it means you have unobtrusive included two times make sure it is included only one time

Comment: I feel dumb, yes it was included twice. It works perfectly now with a (hidden) submit button. I think that workaround deserves to be included in your answer. It is really annoying that the "direct" submit does not do ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was indeed the button that did it - it also works without the AJAX-options and the extra div now.

Comment: yes it was the programmatic submit issue it not subimts form via ajax

Answer (score 1):

The view will have to do something with the returned data. And since you have not told it what to do with it, it is resorting to the default behavior of replacing the current target with the returned value.

How about having the `onChange` event of the `dropdown` call a function that looks like this:

```
function SaveMySelection(paramsToPassToServer) {
    var methodParam = JSON.stringify(paramsToPassToServer);
    var methodUrl = '@Url.Action("MySelection", "Home")';
    var requestType = //GET or POST;
    var successMethod = function (srvResponse) {
    //You can do some parsing of the returned json in case you want to
    //or just ignore the returned value
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: requestType,
        url: methodUrl,
        data: requestType == "POST" ? methodParam : decodeURIComponent($.parseJSON(methodParam)),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        success: successMethod,
        error: FunctionToHandleOnError
    });
}
```

The javascript is not entirely clean as I have quickly adopted from a "parameterised" version that we have implemented but it should give you a general idea.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but my code wasn't hit - now I put at the top of my view and it works... kinda. For some reason, when I use the form submit, my model has the SelectedOption correctly filled, but through this function I receive a model without a SelectedOption (it is null). Tried with dataType text as well, no luck.

Comment: you have to change the return of the method to JSon to work with this code.

Comment: I never got any data _into_ the method, regardless of it's return type. Anyway, I do not need anything back, and the hidden submit button is just one extra line of code. Thanks for the effort anyway!